# Can this code of conditional methods execution be refactored?

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring

If I have some sort of method that does the following:

```
public String validate(Object input) {
    if(input.isTimeInvalid()){
        return "timeInvalid";
    }
    if(input.isChecksumInvalid()){
        return "checksumInvalid";
    }
    if(input.isSignatureInvalid()){
        return "signatureInvalid"
    }
    if(input.isSolutionInvalid()){
        return "solutionInvalid"
    }
    return "valid";
 }
```

So it calls various checking methods in my Object class that do various different validations, and using possibly different data structures as well. Now is there a way to refactor this code to be nicer-looking? Is this a bad code smell?

I recognize if it is conditional on certain variable you can probably use some Map or Polymorphism to extract them out. But in this case, this is more like a try...catch type of logic but still the code looks ugly if I want to add new validation methods later. Is there a design pattern out there for refactoring this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `Chain of Responsibility` Each validator in the chain does its own validation.  If it passes the validator step, then the next validator in the chain runs next and so on.  If the entire chain passes then the object passes validation.

```
interface Validator{
    //throws Exception with error message explaining what failed.
    void validate(Object input) throws ValidationException;
 }


 ....
 private List<Validator> validators;

 public String validate(Object input) {

    for(Validator validator : validators){
          //this is a very ugly try-catch to return String
          //to preserve the original signature of OP
         try{
            validator.validate(input);
         }catch(ValidationException e){
             //failed
             return e.getMessage();
          }

    }
      //all passed
    return "valid";
 }
```